# Can't set my picture as a profile pic?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, profile-picture

I have logged in by using gmail account. I have tried to change the default profile picture but I can't. What's wrong with it? Even it didn't update my google profile picture. Help me to solve this issue. PFA. [image: It's been showing for a long time.]

Comment: Maybe imgur is blocked on your side. When you browse to http://imgur.com/ what do you see? Also, do you see pictures of other users?

Comment: Other people have written to us complaining about the same thing, but I have yet to reproduce it. If this is an odd bug triggered by the phase of the moon, I've yet to find it.

Comment: Yes I can able to access imgur and see pictures of other users.

Answer (score 1):

It takes a little time to show, usually it is caching thing. Anyway I see your photo:

[image]

Isn't this your new profile photo?

Comment: Yes. But I have tried an other picture still it doesn't upload.

Comment: @Balu it does upload, it is just cached, try to delete your browser's cache and you should be able to see it..

Comment: I have cleared browser cache but, still I get this response only.


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/3nE3nX6.png?1